# Error when using Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate. Getting error: File Not Found

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp, pnp-provisioning

I want to copy one site to another clean site. I did it a few times weeks ago and it works good. Now I get an error: File Not Found during export template to pnp file. Any idea why?

```
Connect-PnPOnline -PnPManagementShell -Url https://XXX.sharepoint.com/sites/MDMS

Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Out prototype.pnp -IncludeAllClientSidePages

Connect-PnPOnline -PnPManagementShell -Url https://XXX.sharepoint.com/sites/PolishFuncApp

Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate .\prototype.pnp -ClearNavigation
```

[image]

I turned on Set-PnPTraceLog
[image]

Comment: Can you try to connect without the "-PnPManagementShell" param? After the error occurred you can use Get-PnPException to get the stack trace. I didn't know about Set-PnPTraceLog. Thx for that one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. It turns out that PnP has changed cmdlet

[image]

https://github.com/pnp/powershell

Answer (score 0):

Extracts a provisioning template in PNP format from the current web and all client side pages (if set) from the site collection.

```
Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Out template.pnp -IncludeAllClientSidePages
```

It may be because the prototype.pnp template file does not exist in the scope of the website you specified. Please click [the Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpprovisioningtemplate?view=sharepoint-ps) for more information

You could refer to the following pnp powershell:

```
try{
$srcUrl = Read-Host "Enter the source site url"
$destUrl = Read-Host "Enter the destination site url"
$pageName = Read-Host "Enter the page name which you want to copy"

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $srcUrl -UseWebLogin
$tempFile = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName();
Export-PnPClientSidePage -Force -Identity $pageName -Out $tempFile

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $destUrl -UseWebLogin
Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Path $tempFile
Write-Host "ModernPage is successfully copied."
sleep 10
}
catch{
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red 'Error ',':'$Error[0].ToString();
sleep 10
}
```

**You could refer to the following article to get more information:**

- [COPY SITES PAGE FROM ONE SITE TO ANOTHER USING PNP POWERSHELL](https://www.softreetechnology.com/blogs/copy-sites-page-from-one-site-to-another-using-pnp-powershell/)

…………………………………………………**Updated Answer**……………………………………………

Please follow the steps below to achieve the Copy a Site Collection in SharePoint Online:

Step 1: Connect to the Source site and Get its Schema

```
#Set variables
$SiteURL = "https://test.spo.com/sites/projects "
$SchmaXMLPath = "C:\Temp\SiteSchema.xml"
 
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -UseWebLogin
 
#Get Site Schema
Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Out ($SchmaXMLPath) -PersistBrandingFiles -PersistPublishingFiles
```

Step 2: Create a New Site Collection or Subsite

```
Note:If you have clean site collection, you can skip this step
#Set variables
$SiteURL = "https://test.spo.com/"
 
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -UseWebLogin
 
#Create a new subsite
$NewWeb = New-PnpWeb -Title "New Project" -Url "sites/new" -Description "Team Site for Morocco Project" -Locale 1033 -Template "STS#3"
```

Step 3: Apply the Site Schema into Target Site with [Apply-PnP ProvisioningTemplate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/apply-pnpprovisioningtemplate?view=sharepoint-ps)

```
#Set variables
$SiteURL = "https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/new"
$SchmaXMLPath = "C:\Temp\SiteSchema.xml"
 
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -UseWebLogin
 
#Apply Pnp Provisioning Template
Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Path $SchmaXMLPath -ClearNavigation
```

You could refer to this article:[How to Copy a Site in SharePoint Online using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/08/copy-site-using-powershell-pnp-provisioning-template.html).

………………………………………………***`Updated Answer`***…………………………………………
Please  try to use the following pnp powershell:

```
#Connect to the Source site
$SiteURL= "https://test.spo.com/sites/echo"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -UseWebLogin

#Export the template
Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Out “D:\Test.xml”

#Create new site if your site is not created already
New-PnPSite -Type CommunicationSite -Title 'TESTCommun' -URL https://test.spo.com/sites/echo22

#Or
#New-PnPSite -Type TeamSite -Title 'TESTTeam' -Alias 'Testsite' -IsPublic -URL https://test.spo.com/sites/echo22

#Connect to new site
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://test.spo.com/sites/echo22 -UseWebLogin

#Import the template
Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Path “D:\Test.xml”
```

You coulde refer to this article [Sharepoint PNP: How to copy/clone a SharePoint online site](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52196.sharepoint-pnp-how-to-copyclone-a-sharepoint-online-site.aspx).

Comment: Thank you EchoDu but your solution copy only one page. I need to copy whole site - all lists, pages navigations etc.

Comment: Hi, MAciej. I have updated my answer, hope this helps you.Have a nice day!

Comment: Thank you EchoDu but I found that PnP has changed cmdlet.

Comment: Hi, MAciej. I have updated my answer. I wish you all the best.